# How to check if object exist by Id in tab of json object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I have an array of objects:

```
 var tab =  [
   {
     "id": "1",
     "data" : "blabla" 
   },
   {
      "id": "2",
      "data": "samplesample"
   }
 ]
```

Are there any simple tools for check if an object exist in this array by id.

Something like :

```
 chekexists(tab, "id", "1") ;  // return true
 chekexists(tab, "id", "2") ;  // return true
 chekexists(tab, "id", "3") ;  // return false
 chekexists(tab, "data", "blabla") ;  // return true
 chekexists(tab, "data", "toto") ;  // return false
```

Is this possible to perform this with underscore?

For avoid confusion, my tab is load like this :

```
var tab = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('path'));
```

Comment: i give my answer according to javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use underscore like below:

```
function checkexists(array, prop) {
  return !!_.where(array, prop).length;
}
```

Now you can use it like:

```
checkexists(tab, {id: '1'});
checkexists(tab , "data", "blabla") ;
```

Comment: Hi. I adjust the questions. I'm searching for something more generic. I often have the same problem

Comment: No, `!!` will convert the result to boolean equivalent

Comment: Its like `!0` will give true and `!!0` will give false. similarly `!!1` will be true :)

Comment: I had a look to 'where' method there are also findwhere. So i achive what i was doing with : if( _.findWhere(tab, {'data': 'blabla'}) ==undefined)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `_.findWhere`:

```
function checkexists(list, props) {
  return _.findWhere(list, props) !== undefined;
}

checkexists(tab, {id: 1});
checkexists(tab, {data: 'toto'});
```

Comment: It look like what i'm searching for. i will have a look. Thanks. Do you know if it this method exist in underscore i was not able to find the right one

Answer (score 0):

Easy using the open source project [jinqJs](http://www.jinqjs.com)

```js
var tab =  [
   {
     "id": "1",
     "data" : "blabla" 
   },
   {
      "id": "2",
      "data": "samplesample"
   }
 ]
 
var result = jinqJs().from(tab).where('id == 2').select();

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4) + '</pre><br><br>';

//OR you can do this
result = jinqJs().from(tab).in(['1','2'], 'id').select();
document.body.innerHTML += '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4) + '</pre><br><br>';
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/fordth/jinqJs/master/jinqjs.js"></script>
```